# Which clockwisality should the swastika be in Bleach-related contexts?

Tags: bleach, japanese-language

In the context of Bleach, which clockwisality should the swastika have?

Should it be "卍解", or "卐解"? Or are both valid? Doing a google image search for both of them gets Bleach-related hits.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Zanpakuto](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Zanpakut%C5%8D) article in Bleach wiki says that Bankai is written 卍解. The [Bleach](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLEACH_(%E3%82%A2%E3%83%8B%E3%83%A1)) article in Wikipedia Japanese also mentions lots of 卍解, but no 卐解 found. Both [卍](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%8D%8D) and [卐](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%8D%90) can be read Man/Ban in Japanese.

The 卍 is read [Sauwastika](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sauwastika) in Sanskrit and is more common in Buddhism than Hinduism. In Buddhism the left-facing sauwastika imprinted on the chest, feet, palms of Buddha and also the first of the 65 auspicious symbols on the footprint of the Buddha.

The 卐 is read [Swastika](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swastika) in Sanskrit and is more common in Hinduism than Buddism. In Hinduism the left-facing sauwastika is associated with esoteric tantric practices and often stands for Goddess Kali.